# Promise.map() progress indicator

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, concurrency, promise

I'm trying to concurrently send many GET requests to an JSON API. I'm using Bluebird promises in Node.js, and using [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) for send HTTP requests, like so:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
//urlsArray is a 5000+ array of urls
Promise.map(urlsArray, url => {
  return rp(url)
    .then(results => { 
       return JSON.parse(results);
    }).catch(err => { log(error);});
}).then(resultsArray => {
  log(resultsArray); // print out results
}).catch(err => {
  log(error);
});
```

The problem is that with 5000+ urls in the array, the requests, even concurrently, can take a VERY long time because map() waits till all are done. How can I print out some sort of progress indicator (like a percentage) to the console while map is going through the requests?

I have tried `log(results);` after each request, but that just prints 5000 things to the console, which is not very handy. I'd prefer a percentage, or a number showing approximately how many are done.

Comment: Increment a counter and compare to known array length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that promise chains are just that: Chains. So you can insert a `then` into the chain for each of those promises to do your console update, and have it just pass back the same value it receives.

Actually, looking at your code, you don't even have to do that, as you're already using a per-URL `then` handler to parse the JSON. Just add to that:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
//urlsArray is a 5000+ array of urls
let completed = 0;                                 // ***
Promise.map(urlsArray, url => {
  return rp(url)
    .then(results => { 
       const parsed = JSON.parse(results);
       ++completed;                                // ***
       console.log(`Completed: ${completed}`);     // ***
       return parsed;
    }).catch(err => { log(error);});
}).then(resultsArray => {
  log(resultsArray); // print out results
}).catch(err => {
  log(error);
});
```

(Note I'm parsing the JSON prior to saying that that request completed, in case the JSON is invalid and throws.)

But if you weren't already doing a per-promise activity, you could easily insert a `then` handler. Here's an example of doing that (with native promises, but it would be the same with Bluebird):

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function withoutReportingProgress() {
    return Promise.all(
        data.map(value => new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => {
                resolve(value);
            }, Math.random() * 500);
        }))
    );
}

function withReportingProgress() {
    let completed = 0;                              // ***
    return Promise.all(
        data.map(value => new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(_ => {
                resolve(value);
            }, Math.random() * 500);
        })
        .then(value => {                            // ***
            ++completed;                            // ***
            console.log(`Completed: ${completed}`); // ***
            return value;                           // ***
        }))                                         // ***
    );
}

console.log("Starting without...");
withoutReportingProgress()
    .then(_ => {
        console.log("Done without");
        console.log("Starting with");
        withReportingProgress()
            .then(_ => {
                console.log("Done with");
            });
    });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```